# Why won't ChartLabel print the right country under the right bar chart?

Tags: charts, mathematica-online

I'm working on an assignment and I can't seem to print out the right country name under the right bar chart. What is the problem? Why does the second country only print out?

[image]

Ignore some of the words (they are in Swedish).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your ``worldandtop5countriesbyco2percapita`` probably looks like ``{{5}, {32}, {21}, ...}``. Therefore, use ``Flatten``: ``BarChart[Reverse[Flatten[worldandtop5countriesbyco2percapita]]]``.

Comment: @Domen When I try Flatten I get Bahrain, Kuwait and World only printed, from top to bottom. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Post code in copy-pastable form (InputForm) rather than pictures of code. Include sample data so that the code can be executed with data in the format that you are using.

Comment: Has anyone noticed the `In[ ]` and `Out[ ]` indices? I think a fresh start would be helpful at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some GDP data to work with from WA.

```
gdpList = {{"world", 
   Quantity[8.77985258592209`*^13, ("USDollars")/(
    "Years")]}, {"Qatar", 
   Quantity[1.75837550996185`*^11, ("USDollars")/(
    "Years")]}, {"Kuwait", 
   Quantity[1.3462854274697`*^11, ("USDollars")/("Years")]}, {"UAE", 
   Quantity[4.2114226793765`*^11, ("USDollars")/(
    "Years")]}, {"Bahrain", 
   Quantity[3.85740691489362`*^10, ("USDollars")/(
    "Years")]}, {"Brunei Dar es Salam", 
   Quantity[1.34694229585105`*^10, ("USDollars")/("Years")]}}
```

Extracted labels (i.e., First column of `All` rows)

```
gdpLabels = gdpList[[All, 1]]
```

> {"world", "Qatar", "Kuwait", "UAE", "Bahrain", "Brunei Dar es Salam"}

Similarly the second column of `All` rows has data to be plotted.

(Note: World data is orders of magnitude larger so we plot `Rest@gdpdata` otherwise not much else is visible.

```
 BarChart[Sort@Rest@gdpList[[All, 2]],
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Sort@Rest@gdpLabels, Before],
 AxesLabel -> {"ylabel", "xlabel"},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotLabel -> "The Plot Label"
 ]
```

[image]